# :/slug is not working in my react application

Tags: reactjs

```
  <Route component= {Home} path='/' exact />
  <Route component= {Post} path='/post' />
  <Route component= {About} path='/about' />
  <Route component= {SinglePost} path='/post/:slug' />
  <Route component= {Project} path='/projects' />
```

/post/:slug is not redirecting me to singlePost component. what can be reason .plz help me with this

Comment: Can you share the entire component that these routes are in?

Comment: It's probably matching `Post` rather than `SinglePost`.  Try specifying `exact` for your `Post` route.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it in two different ways.
First solution:

```
  <Route component= {Home} path='/' exact />
  <Route component= {SinglePost} path='/post/:slug' />
  <Route component= {Post} path='/post' />
  <Route component= {About} path='/about' />
  <Route component= {Project} path='/projects' />
```

Second solution:

```
  <Route component= {Home} path='/' exact />
  <Route component= {Post} exact path='/post' />
  <Route component= {About} path='/about' />
  <Route component= {SinglePost} path='/post/:slug' />
  <Route component= {Project} path='/projects' />
```